# How to do Mac App Beta Testing and Distribution?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, mac-app-store, beta-testing

We have developed a Mac app using Unity, so we don't have a Xcode project. However, we made a build and uploaded to iTunes Connect signing with an Application Installer certificate. Submission was successful, and is for release.

Now, we want to test before release. How can we do distribution for Beta Testing?

Things I have tried so far:

​Following the Apple documentation, created some internal and external testers. But can not assign them the app for testing because the pre-release section is not found in the new layout of iTunes Connect as suggested in the Apple docs.

​​​Tried signing the app with the Developer provisioning profile with all the devices added from Member Center and signed with the Developer certificate.

- Can not open the app after installing from pkg.
- Can not upload the app using Application loader. It throws an error 90238: `Invalid provisional Profile: Missing code signing certificate.`

But the Apple docs say that until you upload a build with a provisional profile with all the devices attached to it, devices won't populate, and you can't assign the testers.

Reference links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1884/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html​

Please guide us through this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply . Yes i found the answer.

There is nothing like Mac Beta Testing through iTunes Connect. If you want to test you Mac App,

- make a build using Testing provisional profile/Development
  provisional Profile.
- Before making a new provisional profile make sure you add all the necessary devices in your Apple Member Center and the devices are added in the provisional profile
- Do remember to uncheck the Mac App Validation in Unity3d Build Setting.
- For proper installation of app in your MAC, install it through Terminal.

I am about to write a blog regarding the process of Mac App building and its submission. Will post the link soon .

Comment: Where is the link?

Answer (score 1):

Test Flight does not support Mac apps; only iOS apps.

<strike>I would recommend [Crashlytics Beta](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/), which has a quicker turn-around time anyway as there is no review process and no expiry on builds.  You won't get bug reports however, as there is no Xcode build stage with Unity Mac apps (and therefore no hook to upload symbols).</strike>

Comment: i went all through the site. But i cant find how to integrate unity3d with Fabrics Crashlytics....

Comment: @avisingh Yeah as I mention, you cannot add the crash reporting as there is no Xcode build stage. It's possible that you cannot use their beta testing framework unless you have integrated the crash reporting. I'll update my answer.